# To obey someone

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

As you can see in any dictionary definition, you can obey only laws, rules, regulations and so on, but I can't find a single dictionary has mentioned that you can "obey **someone**"!

Sometimes, I see some quite specific cases in which one can "obey someone".

One in [religous](https://crystalandcomp.com/wives-are-to-obey-their-husband/) contexts or very old-fashioned sources.

or

in some apparently [legal](http://www.admin.cam.ac.uk/offices/hr/ppd/files/gdp-teach&learn_psy&soc_essay.pdf) cases!

What does it mean? Is it an obsolete usage of the word when you want use it with someone rather that something?

Please let me know about it.

Comment: "Obeying" some person is perhaps the most common use of the verb.  I'm surprised you can't find any examples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one:

> **obey**
>    : to follow the commands or guidance of
>  //He always *obeys* his parents.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obey

Here's two:

> **obey**
>
> to do what you are told or expected to do according to someone in authority or a rule or law

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/obey

Here's three:

> **obey**
>
> 1 to do what a law or a person says that you must do
>
> *He told the dog to sit and it immediately obeyed.*
>   *Officers expect their troops to obey them without question.*

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/obey